# Create a function to calculate distance with python

Tags: python, nodes

I want to create a function that calculates the distance between two consecutive elements in the early adopter list, based on the followers' list. If the element is in the first `follower_list` the distance is going to be 1 but. If not, the function needs to look into the next list if the element is in the list the distance will be 2, otherwise 'There is no distance between them'. This is what I have tried so far:

```
early_adopter = ["1","2","3","4"]
follower_list = ["1","c","e","d"]
s2_follower_list = ["b","2","c","d","3"]


def distance(user1, user2):
  path = 0
  for user1 in early_adopter: 
    if user2 in follower_list:
      path =+ 1
    elif user2 in s2_follower_list: 
      path =+ 2 
    else:
      return 'There is no distance between them'


dist = [distance(early_adopter[i], early_adopter[i+1]) for i in range(len(early_adopter)-1)]
dist
```

I want to do something similar with real users connections.

Thanks!!

Comment: i am a little confused. You are sending values from `early_adopter` list into the function `distance`. Then you are overriding the value of `user1` by having the first for loop. isnt that wrong. Shouldnt you use another variable?

Comment: Are you trying to do the following: For every pair of items from `early_adopter`, you want to check if the 1st value is in `follower_list` and second value in `s2_follewer_list` ? If that's the case, you shouldn't have the for loop in the function. Do you agree?

Comment: And what if `user1` is not in `follower_list` but is in `s2_follower_list`. Don't you want to know that? The question is a bit confusing to me. If you can help me understand what you want to do, then we can solve it.

Comment: Hi Joe. Not exactly like you said. It would be something like this: for every consecutive pair of items (user1, user2) from `early_adopter`  I want to check if the user2 (or the second item of the pair) is in one of the lists either  `follower_list` or `s2_follower_list` and depending on where it is the distance will be 1 or 2. (for the hypothetic case if there is another list it will count +1 and it will be the same for an extra list and so on and so forth)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```py
early_adopter = ["1","2","3","4"]
follower_list = ["1","c","e","d"]
s2_follower_list = ["b","2","c","d","3"]


def distance(user1, user2):
  path = 0 
  if user2 in follower_list:
    path += 1
    return path
  elif user2 in s2_follower_list: 
    path += 2
    return path 
  else:
    return 'There is no distance between them'


dist = [distance(early_adopter[i], early_adopter[i+1]) for i in range(len(early_adopter)-1)]
dist
```

Comment: Sorry, This did not work. I've got this as an answer: `[None, None, 'There is no distance between them']`

Comment: Please check the updated code. This should work. The `path` variable was not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
def distance(user1, user2):
  path = []
  if user2 in follower_list:
    path.append(user2)
    return len(path)  
  elif user2 in s2_follower_list: 
    path.append(user2)
    return 1+len(path)
  else:
    return 'There is not distance between them'


dist = [distance(early_adopter[i], early_adopter[i+1]) for i in range(len(early_adopter)-1)]
dist
```

I have found the answer with this code, let me know if you have further suggestions to rewrite the code.